# Html/JS - how can i open file dialog and send the chosen file

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest, openfiledialog

I want to open a file dialog, and send the chosen file (using xmlHttpRequest object) with Basic Authentication header.
I understand that it is a problem to receive the file content.

What is the best solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an `<input type="file">` as part of a standard HTML form.

Comment: I can't get the file data this way

Comment: How (on IE)? I need to use XMLHttpRequest object to send the file to a server. I also want to add a Basic Authentication request header.

Comment: You may want to edit your question to specify these things, and add the `xmlhttprequest` search tag. I don't know the answer (sorry), but doing those things will make it easier for those who know the answer to find your question.

Comment: You won't be able to send the file via an `xmlhttprequest` as there is no way in Javascript to read the contents of a file directly. You will have to use an HTML form to post the file to the server using the `<input type="file">` element

Comment: but how can i add the Authentication header in that way?

Comment: And if i have the username and password in another form, can i use them? how?

Comment: This is probably completely incorrect, but... URLs can include usernames and passwords, for example: `http://username:password@example.com/`. Perhaps you can use JavaScript to transfer the username and password for authentication into the FORM's `action` URL upon submission?